# Modifying value from one data.frame to another data.frame by matching a variable

Tags: r, database, merge

Suppose I have two datasets df1 and df2 as follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Id=c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L),category=c("Na","Na","Na","Na","Na"),stringsAsFactors=F);
df2 <- data.frame(Id=c(1L,3L,5L),stringsAsFactors=F)

> df1
  Id category
1  1       na
2  2       na
3  3       na
4  4       na
5  5       na
> df2
  Id
1  1
2  3
3  5
```

for those ids in df2, I would like to modify the category variable in df1 as "MC" by matching id variable. This looks so simple but having a complicated dataset, how can I do by matching id.

The dataset should look like this.

```
> df1
  Id category
1  1       MC
2  2       na
3  3       MC
4  4       na
5  5       MC
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier option is `%in%`

```
df1$category[df1$Id %in% df2$Id] <- "MC"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an "update join" in data.table terminology

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df1[df2, on = 'Id', category := 'MC']

df1
#    Id category
# 1:  1       MC
# 2:  2       Na
# 3:  3       MC
# 4:  4       Na
# 5:  5       MC
```